# Laravel collections convert key value to key assoc array

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I use this function: `$assets->pluck('url')`.

It outputs: `['link','link1','link2']`

How to convert it to: `[{url: 'link'}, {url: 'link1'}, {url: 'link2'}]`

Comment: Did your collection come from a query perform on a model?

Comment: It came from a relation

Comment: Can you show the code how you got `$assets`?

Comment: Yup, `$assets = auth()->user()->assets;`

Comment: I provide some code bellow

Answer (score 2):

You can add functions to the relation query to only return the `url` field. This way you will get the desired result.

```
$assets = auth()->user()->assets()->select('url')->get();
```

Comment: Cool, but in my case i think a ??magical?? collection method would be more suitable. And just in my opinion collections are pretty poor documented and there's probably a way to do it

Comment: Why would a collection method be better? You will fetch more data from the database and filter in memory?

Comment: No, because of what controller is designed to do - mostly to fetch data. I have a vue frontend which requires url list which laravel provides

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `->only()` collection method to specify the fields you want to return:

```
$assets = auth()->user()
    ->assets
    ->only(['url'])
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

To return a collection of which contain only certain field on model you can add an array of list of fields to retrieve as parameters of the `get` method on your model

```
ModelName::get(['id', 'url']);
```

or by passing list of fields as paremter to the `select` method

```
ModelName::where([...])->select('id', 'url')->get();
```